# Subtracting timestamps in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following select statement where I subtract timestamps for knowing how long a truck has been stopped at a location:

```
 SELECT  f.id, f.imei as imei, f.speed as speed  FROM stops f, stops f2
 where f2.id = f.id-1
 and f.imei = 7466
 and hour(timediff(f2.timestamp,f.timestamp)) * 3600 +   minute(timediff(f2.timestamp,f.timestamp)) * 60 + second(timediff(f2.timestamp,f.timestamp)) > 240 
 and f.speed = 0
 and f2.timestamp >= '2013-08-20 00:00:00' 
 and f2.timestamp <= '2013-08-20 23:59:59'  
 order by f2.timestamp desc
```

The rows for calculating the stops:

```
id imei     timestamp               speed
1  7466     2013-08-20 13:19:00     30    
2  7466     2013-08-20 13:20:00     0 
3  7466     2013-08-20 13:24:30     20
```

So the select gives as result that there was a stop of 4 minutes for the vehicle 7466.

The problem comes when the rows are like this:

```
id imei     timestamp               speed 
1  7466     2013-08-20 13:19:00     30     
2  7466     2013-08-20 13:20:00     0 
3  7466     2013-08-20 13:21:00     0 
4  7466     2013-08-20 13:22:00     0 
5  7466     2013-08-20 13:24:30     20
```

It does not subtract.  How can I get the resulting time?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: What is your final goal? Can you post desired output for the query?

Comment: the desired output would be get the 4 minutes that the truck have been stopped, but when I have several entries with speed 0, the substract does not work, because my select stamente substract the previous and next row.

Comment: Ok. Is `timestamp` of type `timestamp` or `datetime`?

Comment: the type of the field is datetime

Comment: For clarification: you want, for a given `imei`, the difference between the timestamp of the first row where `speed = 0` and the timestamp of the first following row where `speed <> 0` ('following' being defined as having a larger `id`)?

Comment: exactly, do you know how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is correct (see the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b025/6/0) to test it):

```
SELECT
  s1.id AS stopped_row_id, MIN(s2.id) AS departed_row_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s1.timestamp, MIN(s2.timestamp)) AS stopped_seconds
FROM
  stops AS s1
  JOIN stops AS s2 ON
    s1.imei = s2.imei
    AND s1.id < s2.id
    AND (s1.timestamp + INTERVAL 4 MINUTE) <= s2.timestamp
  JOIN stops AS s3 ON
    s1.imei = s2.imei
    AND s3.id = s1.id - 1
  LEFT JOIN stops AS s4 ON
    s1.imei = s2.imei
    AND s4.id BETWEEN (s1.id + 1) AND (s2.id - 1)
    AND s4.speed <> 0
WHERE
  s1.speed = 0
  AND s2.speed <> 0
  AND s3.speed <> 0
  AND s4.id IS NULL
  AND s1.imei = 7466 -- optional; query will also give results for all imei if wanted
  AND s1.timestamp BETWEEN '2013-08-20 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-20 23:59:59' -- optional, query will give results for entire table if wanted
GROUP BY
  s1.id,
  s1.timestamp
```

In this query, `s1` is the 'main' table.
`s2` is joined to provide all rows with higher `id`s than that of `s1` where the `timestamp` is at least 4 minutes higher than that of `s1` (so in essence `s2` is all rows indicating pauses long enough that the row from `s1` should go into the final result set).
`s3` is joined to make sure that the row in `s1` is the *first* row where `speed` is 0 (for your example where there are sets of rows where `speed` is 0).
`s4` is joined to make sure that there are no non-zero-speed rows between the 'selected' rows from `s1` and `s2`.
The `GROUP BY` makes sure that we can get the *first* timestamp in the future where `speed` is not 0 by using `MIN()`.

---

Apparently, the rows are not in a strict descending or ascending order (even if the IDs are). I have reworked the query to only use the time as 'sorting mechanism'. Note that this makes the query very slow, and you might be better off by ordering the table or a solution in the style of that of @peterm. Or at least adding an index on `id` and`timestamp`.

```
SELECT
  s1.timestamp AS stopped_timestamp, MAX(s2.timestamp) as departed_timestamp, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, s1.timestamp, MAX(s2.timestamp)) AS stopped_seconds
FROM
  stops AS s1
  JOIN stops AS s2 ON
    s1.imei = s2.imei
    AND (s1.timestamp + INTERVAL 4 MINUTE) <= s2.timestamp
  JOIN stops AS s3 ON
    s1.imei = s2.imei
  LEFT JOIN stops AS s4 ON
    s1.imei = s2.imei
    AND s4.timestamp BETWEEN (s1.timestamp + INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AND (s2.timestamp - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
    AND s4.speed <> 0
WHERE
  s1.speed = 0
  AND s2.speed <> 0
  AND s3.speed <> 0
  AND s4.id IS NULL
  AND s1.imei = 7466 -- optional; query will also give results for all imei if wanted
  AND s1.timestamp BETWEEN '2013-08-20 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-20 23:59:59' -- optional, query will give results for entire table if wanted
  AND s3.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(s5.timestamp) FROM stops AS s5 WHERE s5.timestamp < s1.timestamp)
GROUP BY
  s1.id,
  s1.timestamp
```

Comment: I'm not getting any record as a result

Comment: I have added a link (at the top) to an SQL Fiddle to test it. It returns one row with '240' in it for me (the number of seconds of the stop duration). Edit: fixed the link to the SQL Fiddle now.

Comment: I'm trying to get it. But I think there is something wrong with my records. What about if instead of the record's order would be descendent instead of asscendent?

Comment: Then you should replace each `-` (like in `s3.id = s1.id - 1`) with a `+`, each `+` with a `-` (like in `s1.timestamp + INTERVAL 4 MINUTE`), each `<` or `<=` (like in `... <= s2.timestamp`) with a `>` or `>=` and each `>` or `>=` with a `<` or `<=`.

Comment: it is not working, I have took a paste of the columns with the real order http://pastebin.com/jZrBqNP9

Comment: I have modified the script and the order of the timestamp as it is stored in the database, but I'm getting just a result, here it is the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cbcb/3

Comment: well, I think I got it, but in my local mysql database the script is frozen when I run it, in the other hand in sql fidle works ok

Comment: Your data set contains unsorted timestamps (see rows 9, 10 and 11): they go forward in time, then backward in time, then forward in time again. Is this correct or a typo or something?

Comment: it is corrected now. Anyway it is working in sql fiddle but in my database with real data and sorted correctly it takes a lot of time to complete the process and show the data, maybe it is because I have 6700 rows at the momment for calculate, does the script be faster? My above script does it very fast, it takes 2 seconds, but it does not calculate when there is midle records with zero values for the speed

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a truck that is stopped for longer than 4 minutes (240 seconds). See the following line of your SQL query.

```
hour(timediff(f2.timestamp,f.timestamp)) * 3600 + 
minute(timediff(f2.timestamp,f.timestamp)) * 60 + 
second(timediff(f2.timestamp,f.timestamp)) > 240
```

In the following table...

```
id imei     timestamp               speed     
1  7466     2013-08-20 13:20:00     0 
2  7466     2013-08-20 13:21:00     0 
3  7466     2013-08-20 13:22:00     0 
2  7466     2013-08-20 13:24:00     20
```

In none of these pairs are the trucks stopped for longer than 4 minutes (240 seconds). Because those pairs do NOT satisfy your WHERE conditions, they are not selected.

Comment: The time is irrelevant... 120/240 does not matter, because the rows do not satisfy your WHERE conditions, they are simply not selected

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** One way to do it

```
SELECT duration / 60 duration
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, imei, timestamp, speed, 
         @d := IF(@s = 0 AND speed > 0, 
                  @d := @d + TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @t, timestamp),
                  @d) duration, 
         @t := IF(@s = 0 AND speed = 0, @t, timestamp),
         @s := speed 
    FROM stops, (SELECT @d := 0, @s := -1, @t = 0) i
   WHERE imei = 7466
     AND timestamp >= '2013-08-20 00:00:00' AND timestamp <= '2013-08-20 23:59:59' 
   ORDER BY timestamp
 ) z
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
+----------+
| duration |
+----------+
|        4 |
+----------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0b9a2/12)** demo

Comment: I have extended the data set in your Fiddle in [a new Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b025/2/0). Using that data set, I get very odd results using your query. I can't seem to explain them given your (admittedly daunting) query, though.

Comment: @TomasCreemers It returns 16.5 min (4+8+2+2.5) and it's exactly what it should be I believe. Here is **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b025/3)**

Comment: Then I misunderstood what was asked. I thought it should return the length of each stop over four minutes long, not the sum of the length of all stops. (See also the clarification in the comments of the question.)

Comment: I'm trying to get it. But I think there is something wrong with my records. What about if instead of the record's order would be descendent instead of asscendent?

Comment: @FranRod It's a 'running total' type of query and it relies on correct order of records in this case ascending by time. Can you post records with which you can't get the correct result? This way we can fix the query if needed.

Comment: @peterm Hello, here you have a sample data directly from my database http://pastebin.com/jZrBqNP9

Comment: @FranRod The result that query gives on your data set is 99.5667 min. What result are you expecting?

Comment: hello Peterm after some dayys trying to do it, at last it is working well.

Comment: @FranRod Great. If you feel like it was helpful please, consider to **[upvote/accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.